# hits>total - Limited to 10000 records - Increase the limit

Tags: python-3.x, elasticsearch

[image]

My API request looks like this...
`GET /my_index/_search?scroll=1m`

Along with getting the search results, I'm also looking to get the count of the total results at one go. However, while targeting `hits>total>value`, the number of records never show a count more than 10000. Due to this, I have to fire count API separately. Is there any way where I can get more than 10000 records in my same `_search` query?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Simply add `"track_total_hits": true` to your request.

(see Elasticsearch Reference: [Track total hits](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/search-your-data.html#track-total-hits))

Answer (score 6):

Try to set `track_total_hits` search option to `true`.

> Generally the total hit count can’t be computed accurately without visiting all matches, which is costly for queries that match lots of documents. The `track_total_hits parameter` allows you to control how the total number of hits should be tracked. Given that it is often enough to have a lower bound of the number of hits, such as "there are at least 10000 hits", the default is set to 10,000. This means that requests will count the total hit accurately up to 10,000 hits. It’s is a good trade off to speed up searches if you don’t need the accurate number of hits after a certain threshold.
>
> When set to true the search response will always track the number of hits that match the query accurately

There is a [great article](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.1/search-request-track-total-hits.html) from the official documentation describing what it is.

Or, if you only need total count, just use [Count API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-count.html):